# Make web site to be seen to known password

Tags: asp.net, iis

I don't have much experience with ASP.NET and IIS - 
But I created some simple web site and i put it on IIS server - 
I want to make the access to be only for those users, who are know the access password.

How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you had a look at [Forms Authentication Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wff0kyh.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with Forms Authentication in asp.net. Take a look at some information on the web about this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPDOTNETauthentication.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx

It is pretty easy to get this working, most of the work is in the web.config and it gives you a lot of control about what pages are secure and what pages are not.

Comment: If i createing one more aspx page that will contain 'login' dialog - and the user enter the right username&password => how can i show the main aspx page ? how can i make the swap between those two pages from code ?

Comment: take a look at this link. it might answer your 2nd question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy.aspx